# How do you compute expressions with operators like gradient, divergence or curl?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, vector-analysis, curl

I know that it is not an objective question, but I ask for advices and tips for succesfully compute expressions like :

$\nabla \cdot \nabla f$

$ \nabla\cdot \nabla \times F$

$ \nabla\cdot(fF)$

$  \nabla\times\nabla \times F$

$\nabla\times (fF)$

I'm sorry if my question is vague... It's just that I have many troubles to compute those things. I'm not even sure if what I wrote is something that makes sense ! And perhaps, I'm not the only one struggling with those ugly symbols ?

**Could you please help me ? I really need to know how to develop expressions with those operators, and even after a few months trying, I still do not have a good method.**

Comment: You can use `\operatorname{div} \operatorname{grad} f` to produce $\operatorname{div} \operatorname{grad} f$.

Comment: Anyway, the question is rather vague. I suggesting adding an example or two and showing your attempts at computing them, so that potential answerers will be able to tailor advice to you.

Comment: ok I'll do this in an instant :)

Comment: @Travis I mean, for all of them I have the solution. But I just don't know what to do when I see the operator. What is the order of the things... how to read it etc... For instance, the last one I tried was the rot of the rot of f. And I find it extremely hard to do... because everything is intertwined and mixed...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say you have a vector field $F=\langle F_1,F_2,F_3\rangle.$ Then it's divergence is 
$$\nabla\cdot F=\frac{\partial F_1}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial F_2}{\partial y}+\frac{\partial F_3}{\partial z}.$$
On the other hand, if you have a scalar function $f(x,y,z)$ then it's gradient is 
$$\nabla f=\langle f_x,f_y,f_z\rangle,$$
where $f_x$ is the partial derivative of $f$ with respect to $x$ and so on. Now putting these two things together you 
$$\text{div grad f }=\nabla \cdot (\nabla f)=\nabla\cdot \langle f_x,f_y,f_z\rangle = f_{xx}+f_{yy}+f_{zz}.$$

For the last one, consider $F=\langle A,B,C\rangle.$ Then
$$\text{ rot (rot F)} = \nabla \times \langle C_y-B_z,A_z-C_x,B_x-A_y \rangle$$
$$ =\langle (B_x-A_y)_y-(A_z-C_x)_z,(C_y-B_z)_z-(B_x-A_y)_x,(A_z-C_x)_x-(C_y-B_z)_y\rangle$$
$$ = \langle B_{xy}-A_{yy}-A_{zz}+C_{xz},C_{yz}-B_{zz}-B_xx+A_{yx},A_{zx}-C_{xx}-C_{yy}+BB_{zy} \rangle.$$
You need to work from the inner operator to the outer one when solving problems of this kind.